# Why Can't I move an Element of a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, constants, move

I want to be able to change the key of an element of a `map`.

I thought that a good way to handle that would be to `move` the element from the `map`, as follows:

```
map<char, int> foo{{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}};

foo['z'] = move(*foo.find('c')).second;

for(auto& i: foo){
    cout << i.first << ' ' << i.second << endl;
}
```

This outputs:

> a 1
>   b 2
>   c 3
>   z 3

Rather than my hoped:

> a 1
>   b 2
>   z 3

Is there a way that I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `move` doesn't move anything; it just converts its argument into an *rvalue*, so that something else can move from it. Secondly, moving from an object doesn't destroy it, or remove it from a container, it just leaves it in a valid, unspecified state. Finally, "moving" a simple type like `pair<const char, int>` just consists of copying it (especially as the `const` means you can't modify the key anyway, and will break the map if you force it to change).

So the move alone does nothing, and your code is equivalent to

```
foo['z'] = foo.find('c')->second;
```

which just adds a new element with a copy of the same mapped value.

You can move the mapped value to the new element, and then remove the old one.

```
auto found = foo.find('c');
if (found != foo.end()) {
    foo['z'] = move(found->second);
    foo.erase(found);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to change the key of an element of a map.

You can't. The `value_type` of a `map` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. The `const` part is important. The entire internal layout of the structure is predicated on making sure that `insert`s go in the right place. If you could just change the key, you could make the entire structure invalid.

The code you're running:

```
foo['z'] = move(*foo.find('c')).second;
```

Just inserts the pair `('z', foo['c'])` - the `move` doesn't do anything. Remember: `move` is just a cast to rvalue reference - it doesn't do anything unless it's actually `move`d from, which nothing is doing here and wouldn't make a difference anyway since we're dealing with fundamental types. The above line of code is equivalent to:

```
foo['z'] = foo.find('c')->second;
```

which might explain why you're seeing the behavior of just inserting a new key/value pair without `'c'` getting erased.

The right way to "change" a key is to erase it and then insert it:

```
auto it = foo.find('c');
if (it != foo.end()) {
    foo.insert(std::make_pair('z', it->second));
    foo.erase(it);
}
```